# How to convert a 2-dimensional map from Firestore into Typescripts interface type

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the field value from Firebase's Firestore, the type of the value is basically a `Map<string, Map<string, dynamic>>`. How do I define and deserialize that kind of an object in TypeScript?

The Firestore document data, the users field is causing issues

```
{
  "movies": {

  },
  "name": "watchlist #1",
  "users": {
    "userId": {
      "alias": "user",
      "notify": false,
    }
  }
}
```

```
export interface Watchlist {
    movies: Map<string, WatchlistMovie>,
    name: string
    users: Map<string, WatchlistUser>
}

export interface WatchlistMovie {
    watchedBy: string[]
}

export interface WatchlistUser {
    alias: string
    notify: boolean
}

export function toWatchlist(snapshot: admin.firestore.DocumentSnapshot): Watchlist {
    const data = snapshot.data()!!;
    return {
        movies: data.movies,
        name: data.name,
        users: data.users
    };
}
```

When I try to update the users field at the moment I get the following error.

`TypeError: watchlist.users.set is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you cannot without additional package and [Class transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) is great for it. Check specially [plainToClass documentation](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#enforcing-type-safe-instance)

Here is sample code:

```js
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { plainToClass, Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { stringify } from 'querystring';

export class Watchlist {
  @Type(() => Map)
  movies: Map<string, WatchlistMovie>;

  name: string;

  @Type(() => Map)
  users: Map<string, WatchlistUser>;
}

export class WatchlistMovie {
  watchedBy: string[];
}

export class WatchlistUser {
  alias: string;
  notify: boolean;
}

const data = {
  movies: {
    Shrek: {
      watchedBy: ['Me', 'You']
    }
  },
  name: 'watchlist #1',
  users: {
    userId: {
      alias: 'user',
      notify: false
    }
  }
};

const converted = plainToClass(Watchlist, data);

const movieWatchList = new WatchlistMovie();
movieWatchList.watchedBy.push('abc');
converted.movies.set('Avatar', movieWatchList);
console.log(converted);
```

Comment: Your welcome. Works for many purposes :) But sometimes it has a problem with some nested and more complex structures. Although I always solved what I needed